# Count the output rows of an sql query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    `list_type`.`type`
FROM
    `events`
        INNER JOIN
    `list_type` ON `events`.`type` = `list_type`.`id`
WHERE
    `events`.`date` BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'
        AND `events`.`center_id` = 2
GROUP BY `events`.`name`

Baseline
Baseline
Baseline
Baseline
Baseline
Baseline
Baseline
Special Events
Special Events
Special Events
```

But I would like it to count each type like this

```
Baseline    7
Special Events  3
```

so i tried this

```
SELECT 
    `list_type`.`type`,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    `events`
        INNER JOIN
    `list_type` ON `events`.`type` = `list_type`.`id`
WHERE
    `events`.`date` BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'
        AND `events`.`center_id` = 2
GROUP BY `events`.`name`
```

But it gives me this:

```
Baseline    45
Baseline    3
Baseline    56
Baseline    23
Baseline    12
Baseline    9
Baseline    2
Special Events  5
Special Events  4
Special Events  18
```

It is counting the number of each name and type not the output form query.
I also tried COUNT(`list_type`.`type`) 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried  `count(distinct list_type.type) `

Answer (score 1):

You can always count the result of your query using a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT type, count(*)
FROM (
  ...your query above...
) s
GROUP BY type
```

it will surely work, but it's not necessarily the best way to proceed. I think you should just group by `list_type.type`:

```
GROUP BY list_type.type
```

and then you have to count distinct events name for every type, like this:

```
SELECT 
    `list_type`.`type`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `events`.`name`)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I did this in the past but did not add the "s" after the ) so it did not work.

Comment: @user1658688 you're welcome! MySql requires that you give an alias to all subqueryes, I used just `s` that stands for subquery, but you can use something more descriptive like `groupedEvents` or anything you like

Comment: @user1658688 pls don't forget to accept the answer if you find it useful :) tnx

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP`ed then by `list_type.type`

```
SELECT  list_type.type,
        COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM    events
        INNER JOIN list_type 
            ON events.type = list_type.id
WHERE   events.date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'
        AND events.center_id = 2
GROUP   BY list_type.type
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't group by `events.name`

Try grouping by `list_type`.`type`

Since you were grouping by event, then it was giving you results and numbers based on events!